# Can cPanel run on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, web-server, apache-httpd, cpanel

Is it possible to run cPanel on Raspbian? I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, and I want to know if this is possible before I go on purchasing cPanel. I currently have a virtual server on my Raspberry Pi. I use Webmin and Virtualmin on that server currently. It will be OK to continue using that management interface if cPanel on Raspbian is impossible.

Comment: Install Webmin on http://www.webmin.com, cPanel is too heavy for RASPI3.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install CentOS 7 for raspberry pi here: http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/isos/armhfp/ I haven't tested this, but I am sure that once you're running CentOS you'll be able to use the standard cPanel installation script. :)

Edit: You'll see that (at the time of writing) there is an image for raspberry pi 2, and another for raspberry pi 3